# elementary OS boots into the command line interface

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers

After upgrading the graphics card, the system does not start properly. It boots to black screen without showing up the user interface. Please help me.

Comment: Please add some more information. Some error messages while booting, etc.? Which graphics card, how upgraded?

Comment: uninstall the graphic card via tty and try again.

Comment: You can try to switch to the GUI session by pressing `ctrl + alt + F7`, but you will more than likely need to install the proper drivers for your new graphics card. What card did you upgrade to, and what was your old card?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem after having installed bad drivers for my graphic card, so in my opinion it's a problem related to some **not working open source driver** that are being installed by elementary. You can try downloading the correct drivers from your graphic card's producer's website and **install them manually** from the command line interface, this should solve the problem.
In my case I had to reinstall the system, if you have nothing to lose, also try to **install elementary again**.